# Spring Boot multi module WAR Generation

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have made a maven Spring boot (REST) Project that has 3 (maven) sub modules (i. api ii. implementation and iii. service modules).

The main method (@SpringBootApplication) is in the root of the project. The REST web service works fine from IDE but maven does not allow me to package this project as war and deploy to external tomcat.

To solve this I added a new module and added dependencies of other modules within this and packaged this as war (by adding maven-war-plugin). But when deployed on server; the webservice does not get hit.

Structure-

Service Project

- main()(This is within root project)
- api module
- service module
- implementation module
- Newly added module (that has above 3 modules injected as dependency and the plugin that let me package this as a war)

Expecting a war that has all these submodules that can be deployed on external Tomcat 9 server.

How to achieve this?

Please Note - I have added    spring-boot-maven-plugin
to repackage in the root project, but it is not working.

Comment: Your **.war** and `webservice` are in different context path or same?

Comment: .war i am creating from this _spring bootrest webservice project_ itself.
So context path for after I build **abc.war** will be **/abc/** and I will access it from browser if deployed as http://localhost:8080/abc/greet and if I test is from spring boot I enter http:localhost:8080/greet

Comment: Well, then what is your webservice context-path? Seems it may be a CORS issue. https://spring.io/understanding/CORS

Comment: Nope, CORS is handled in the code. My question is - Can I get a .war from this project structure. If yes, how.

Comment: Then what errors do you face actually ?

Comment: If I start the webservice from IDE I am able to access the websservice. But I am unable to deploy this as a war file on external tomcat server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160870/discussion-between-jmd-and-ataur-rahman-munna).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding parent to this newly added module fixed the issue and I was able to make a working jar!

Comment: jar or war?! :)